# How to assign a multiple column names to a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am having dataset which has 10000 rows and 300 columns. All the 300 columns in the dataset named as a 0, 1, 2, 3 .. 300. I have all 300 column names in the text document. I wanted to assign all these 300 column names to my dataset automatically.

I can create a list for all these 300 column names and assign to my dataset. However, this is time-consuming as I am doing manually. Any other method is available?

```
# Creating list for all 300 column names
column_names = ['a', 'b', ... 'ah']  

# my dataframe name is train

train.columns = column_names
```

Comment: These column names can be random or u need them like [a,b,c ----- z]

Comment: No these columns are not random. columns names in notepad as order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the text into a list and assign to column name.

**Ex:**

```
with open('filename') as infile:    #'filename' == Your text file. 
    column_names = [line.strip() for line in infile]

train.columns = column_names
```